# Block external Window (TV-Out) from changing orientation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiinterfaceorientation

I'm playing around with the TV-out Adapter for the iphone. My goal is to have an external window display on my tv in order to play movies from my iphone.

the big problem I've got now, is that if the phones orientation changes (physically) the window that shows on the tv turns as well. which is of course unwanted behaviour..

So far i return NO from shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation. But it still turns and turns.

I'm very grateful for any help on that topic

cheers

sam..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah well the solution was rather simple.
I had to assign a RootViewController to the Window that I'm using. Said Rootviewcontroller then needs to implement a shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation Method (that of course returns NO).